# How to add json data as parameter to c.Body.Request?

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a function named `LoginUser(c *gin.Context)` with argument `c *gin.Context`. I want to call `LoginUser` from another function `CreateBlogsWithUser`. But `LoginUser` requires `username and password`. I tried to pass in `c.Request.Body` but it is not working.

```
func (server *Server) CreateBlogsWithUser() {
    resp := httptest.NewRecorder()
    gin.SetMode(gin.TestMode)
    c, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(resp)
    c.Request.Header.Add("Content-Type","application/json")
    c.Request.Body.Add("uname","test") //this line is not working
    c.Request.Body.Add("password","test@123")  //this line is not working
    LoginUser(c)
}

func LoginUser(c *gin.Context) {
    requestData := models.CCPADefaultData{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(c.Request.Body).Decode(&requestData)
    if err != nil {
        errList["Invalid_body"] = "Missing request parameters."
        c.JSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "status": http.StatusUnprocessableEntity,
            "error":  "Always come in this if condition.",
        })
        return
    }
    //XXXXXXXXX
    //Code
}
```

I tried many things but none is working for me.
Please help how to pass parameter if argument is `c *gin.Context`

Comment: Don't do that, handler functions aren't supposed to be called by other handlers. Just define a normal, non-handler function that's used by both `LoginUser` and `CreateBlogsWithUser`.

Comment: Actually I have to call handler function for mocking I am not getting any way to do that. I mean I can test handler function but other function inside ```CreateBlogsWithUser``` are not mocked. any suggestion

Comment: 1. Do not attempt to *"add json data as parameter to c.Body.Request"* period. 2. If you have to pass extra info using `gin.Context` then try using the [`Keys`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Keys) field, you can set values to it by using the [`Set`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Set) method and retrive values from it by using any of the `GetXxx` methods. 3. In Go plain functions are *not* mockable. You *can* mock interfaces and function *values* (e.g. function variables, fields, arguments) but *not* functions. You cannot mock `LoginUser`. Not in Go.

Comment: can i mock LoginUser()?

Comment: No, you can not.